# Break out of loop and continue with next iteration after a certain time?

Tags: r

Hi supposed I have something like this.

```
s = c( 1, 10, 20, 2, 3, 300 )
for ( i in 1:1000 ){
  
  Sys.sleep( sample ( s, 1 ))
  # break if it longer than 20 seconds? 
  print ( "done") 
}
```

What I want to the loop to do is to break and continue if a command takes more than 20 secs?

thanks.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/setTimeLimit.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this serves your purpose:

```
for ( i in 1:1000 ){
      wait <- sample ( s, 1 )
      if(wait > 20) break
      else {
          # print(wait)  
          Sys.sleep( wait)
          print ( "done") 
      }
  }
```

`print(wait)` is an optional way to know the sampled `wait`.